# How can I send both a string and an int to an ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ViewModel command that looks like this:

```
// Category Page
private ICommand openPageCmd;
public ICommand OpenPageCmd =>
    openPageCmd ??
    (openPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) => settingsPage.OpenPage(pageType)));
```

But instead of sending a string I would like to send an ID which is an int and a Name which is a string.  Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own command by implementing `ICommand`. Create a command having a constructor with the required parameters.

See:

- [ICommand Interface (System.Windows.Input)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx).
- [ICommand Interface in WPF (Code Project)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1052346/ICommand-Interface-in-WPF).

```
public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;

    public MyCommand(int id, string name)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //TODO: Add your implementation
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Or better, create your own relay command (generic reusable command):

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly T _argument;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(T argument, Action<T> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _argument = argument;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(_argument);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

The view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private SettingsPage settingsPage = new ...;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        OpenPageCmd =
            new RelayCommand<MyViewModel>(this, vm => settingsPage.OpenPage(vm.Id, vm.Name));
    }

    public ICommand OpenPageCmd { get; }
}
```

This allows the command to use the current values of the view model at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with the relay command. Is that better in some way than the ICommand? What would be the advantages?

Comment: Can you also show the ICommand solution that you replace with ICommand.  Thanks

Comment: [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) is the interface that all commands implement. By itself it does nothing. The implementations do. I don't know what your `Command<T>` class is, but it seems to be some kind of relay command. Relay command is just a common name for a command that is generic, i.e., whose behavior is defined by an `Action` parameter. The details depend on how `settingsPage.OpenPage` is implemented.

Comment: My `RelayCommand<T>` and `MyViewModel` examples are this `ICommand` solution that you will have to adapt to your needs. Note that this `RelayCommand<T>` can be used for all your commands as long as you don't need another implementation of `CanExecute` or need to raise `CanExecuteChanged`. The relay command does what you pass it as lambda, for example: `vm => settingsPage.OpenPage(vm.Id, vm.Name)`.